# Azure DevOps CICD with .NET framework web app

Tags: .net, git, azure-pipelines, cicd

We have a git repo on Azure DevOps where we are developing a web app using .NET framework 4.6.1
It's a small web API that using Swagger and runs fine locally with IIS express.
We have set up an App Service on Azure to host the website and it works fine to publish from Visual Studio and it works like a charm.

Now, we want to set up a proper Continuous Integration (CICD) pipelines using Azure DevOps so that it all builds and publishes on auto.

We have created a pipeline for the Dev branch of the repo with the following Agent job:

1. Use NuGet 4.4.1
2. NuGet restore
3. Build solution (msbuild arguments below)

> /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:DeleteExistingFiles=True /p:publishUrl="$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\WebAppContent"

4. Archive (root folder to archive below)

> $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\WebAppContent

5. Publish symbols path
6. Publish artifact

And it works well. All is built, archived in to a ZIP and published as an artifact (or so it seems!)

We have then set up a release pipeline that triggers when a new build is available. Agent is connected with subscription and to the hosting service. (we have other .NET Core applications that deploys fine)

Agent is as follows:

1. Azure Web App Deploy - using Azure Web App (Package or folder)

> $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip

We have no errors! All seems good but there are no changes on the hosting website on Azure. It's like the website is published at the wrong place on it since we receive a warning that the page doesn't exist when we try to access it.

We've tried different solutions with ZIP deploy/Auto detect/Run from package and using Azure App Service Deploy.

What have we missed?

Comment: Your second pipeline will have a new working directory. Do you have a step where it fetches the artefact from the other build?

Comment: The Azure Web App Deploy fetches the artifact from the mentioned Package or folder and according to the logs it seems to be good:
`2021-09-16T07:05:25.2075666Z Downloading artifacts for build: 1254
2021-09-16T07:05:25.3720824Z Downloading items from container resource #/4593467/drop
2021-09-16T07:05:25.3721622Z Downloading artifact drop from: https://X.visualstudio.com//_apis/resources/Containers/4593467?itemPath=drop&isShallow=true&api-version=4.1-preview.4
...
2021-09-16T07:05:27.4754872Z ##[section]Finishing: Download artifact - REPO BRANCH - drop`

Comment: Unfortunately not much I can see from here. I'd need your entire setup and logs to determine what the issue is. Maybe someone else has more experience and has run into this before though

Comment: It's indeed tricky. We have several other repos (both production and development) running properly with CICD and all goes well... they are however .NET Core & .NET 5.0 applications. This is the only one still running on Framework.